# How do you keep the command prompt open when using Java?

Tags: java, command-line, ping

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class PingTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
           {"cmd","/k","start","cmd","/c","ping localhost"});
    }
}
```

It pings the localhost like I want it to, but it doesn't stay open.  It closes right away once it's done.  What do I do to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're basically executing

```
cmd /k start cmd /c ping localhost
```

It does exactly what it should, runs `start` which runs `cmd` which terminates after `ping` finishes because of the `/c` flag.

If you want the window with the ping results to stay open you need to do

```
cmd /k start cmd /k ping localhost
```

or

```
cmd /c start cmd /k ping localhost
```

(Doesn't matter what the flag on the first `cmd` is because it isn't opening a new window.)

Comment: What worked for me was cmd /k start cmd /k ping localhost, but your suggestion basically solved it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer actually I just found out you need `cmd` for `start` to work. Turns out `start` isn't a program, it's a command-line command (like `dir` or `cd`).

Answer (score 4):

One cheap fix is to request input at the end of main().

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    ...

    System.out.println("Press return to continue.");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, what this does takes place in the Console, not the command prompt

Comment: What is the operating system you're using, where do the command prompt and console appear, and how do they differ? For example, are you using the Windows "Command Prompt" cmd.exe?

Comment: Windows 7, cmd.exe.  Command prompt appears in its own window.  The console is part of the compiler (Eclipse) I'm using

Comment: Since you're launching cmd.exe yourself, you can use the option to keep it open: cmd.exe /S /K <command> . Not sure why you have cmd.exe /C, which says to terminate after running the command.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the built in command `pause`. For that you can extend you command like that:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
       {"cmd", "/k", "start", "cmd", "/c", "\"ping localhost & pause\""});
}
```